# Allow tab navigation for a button within a div. If the div is focussed?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am having a component like this: (Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-platform-1ry6b2?file=/src/App.js)
[image]

The green part is div. Here's my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [insideApp, setInsideApp] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div onFocus={() => setInsideApp(true)} onBlur={() => setInsideApp(false)}>
      <div className="App">
        <input className="input" />
        {insideApp && <button>Show Button</button>}
      </div>
      <p>Out of Box content</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
/* css */
.App {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid aqua;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 2vw;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.App:focus-within {
  border: 2px solid lime;
}

.input {
  flex: auto;
}
```

What I want ideally is when I navigate to the button through tab it should get highlighted as shown below:

[image]

However since I am rendering the button conditionally I am losing focus. Can someone help me come up with some innovative idea to achieve the same? I want the div to change to lime when its focussed and then do a tab navigation such that it detects input as well as button.

Also I want button to be only shown when focus is within the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use plain CSS to handle all the process:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  // const [insideApp, setInsideApp] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="App">
        <input className="input" />
        <button>Show Button</button>
      </div>
      <p>Out of Box content</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid aqua;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 2vw;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.App:focus-within {
  border: 2px solid lime;
}

.App button {
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.App:focus-within button {
  display: flex;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.input {
  flex: auto;
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. Use `:focus-within` to conditionally display the button
2. Disable cursor events for the `button` element and hide it as default to prevent interactions
3. Enable cursor events and display the `button` when `:focus-within` is active

Comment: When someone does it all using plain CSS that just touches from deep inside. Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have look to SyntheticEvents https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

There are two events `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to you use these two events for highlighting the div and hiding the button.

```
<div
      onMouseEnter={() => setInsideApp(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setInsideApp(false)}
    >
      <div className="App">
        {insideApp ? (
          <div>
            <input className="input" />

            <button>Show Button</button>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
      <p>Out of Box content</p>
    </div>
```